# How to format Azure DevOps console Logs

Tags: logging, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I am looking for a way to see the one line logs in azure devops to multiple lines. sometimes its difficult to debug the issues that are in one line.
Is their any way we can format the azure devops log such a way that all the log content should fit in one screen instead of scrolling to right?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 2):

As of this time, however, formatting Azure DevOps logs is not supported.

Here are some alternative methods:

1. Click "View raw log" in the upper right corner. Then the log will fit the screen but you can only see the log text, not the color hint for log.

   [image]
2. Download the log in the run page, and then use Visual Code or other tools to view.

   [image]

Comment: Hi @Jane as you mentioned their is no inbuilt method for log formatting. but one way i find out is to take all the logs to a variable and then split it with comas. it will give us a well good log